# Embedded PDF object tag File Name

Tags: html, object, pdf

I have a pdf embedded in an `object` tag in `html5`.

```
<object id="framePDF" ng-if="vm.ShowPanel" data="{{'data:application/pdf;base64,'+ vm.URL}}"
        style="width:100%; height:99%; overflow-y:hidden" type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

I'd like if there a way to a name to the file. By default it appears "data:"

[image]

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in vm.URL?

If it's a PDF file you can remove the **'data:application/pdf;base64,'+** from your code.

```
<object id="framePDF" ng-if="vm.ShowPanel" data="{{vm.URL}}"
    style="width:100%; height:99%; overflow-y:hidden" type="application/pdf">
</object>
```

If it's an endpoint flushing bytes as response, your filename will be always the action name of the endpoint. In this case, you can configure your application to accept dynamic endpoint in {endpoint}/{filename} format.

Update: create html of object tag using javascript and then add it to the dom. I did this and it worked for me on edge and IE too.